# Best multi-chain provider?

Tags: rpc, api

What’s the best multi-chain provider? I want to use Polygon, Avalanche, BNB, Solana, & Ethereum. Having low latency and reliability are my main requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am biased; QuickNode is a leading multi-chain blockchain provider with 22+ chains. It has been the fastest and most performant provider in the space for quite some time now. With a global network of nodes, it gives the lowest latency and has robust, reliable infrastructure.

Blogposts on deep research comparing different providers:

1. https://blog.quicknode.com/quicknode-the-quickest-solana-node-provider/
2. https://blog.quicknode.com/justifying-quick-in-quicknode-response-time-comparison-of-various-blockchain-node-providers/

Check out all supported chains here: https://www.quicknode.com/chains

Answer (score 1):

If you mean RPC providers, you might want to check out these providers:

- [Alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com/)
- [Ankr](https://www.ankr.com/)
- [NodeReal](https://nodereal.io/)
- [Omnia](https://omniatech.io/)
- [Portal](https://www.portal.pokt.network/)
- [QuickNode](https://www.quicknode.com/)
- [RockX](https://www.rockx.com/)

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion, if you are looking for the best multi-chain provider at an affordable price then look for [Multichain providers](https://www.bloctechsolutions.com/multichain-development-services/)